# Operator '==' incompatible with operand types 'Guid' and 'Guid' using DynamicExpression.ParseLambda<T, bool>

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, dynamic-linq

I'm Using 
[Dynamic Linq library](http://www.lcs.syr.edu/faculty/fawcett/handouts/CoreTechnologies/CSharp/samples/CSharpSamples/LinqSamples/DynamicQuery/Dynamic%20Expressions.html)  and there is 
[Source code and basic docu](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/231706/Dynamic-query-with-Linq) and the Nuget version

**PM> Install-Package DynamicLINQ**

I'm trying to construct a where clause that involves Guids

I have tried with the string `"Id == @0"`.
The parameter array is just an `object[]` with the value (`Guid xxxx`)

```
  var whereClauseSB = BuildLogicalKeyWhereClause2(entity, logicalKey);  //build string
  var parms = BuildParamArray(entity, logicalKey); // object[]
  var whereLambda = Ofsi.Bos.Core.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda<T, bool>(whereClauseSB.ToString(),parms);  //parse
```

an exception is thrown in DynamicExpression.ParseLambda

> Operator '==' incompatible with operand types 'Guid' and 'Guid'

- I have also tried with GUID and String.(fail)
- I tried with and "Id = @0" (fail).
- String == string works, as does Int32==int32 but not Guid == Guid  does not

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps there is a bug in the code as `Guid` is noted to have explicit support in their documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the `Equals` method instead of the `==` operator in your string:

```
"Id.Equals(@0)"
```

Comment: ObjectDirectoryId.Equals(@0) && ObjectId == @1  && CultureName == @2 with the matching object[] just got parsed. :-)  I will mark as correct answer once the test is complete but it looks good . Thanks pswg

Comment: It's very good but I had a problem with Nullable Guid. I got this exception
 Expression of type 'System.Guid' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Object' of method 'Boolean Equals(System.Object)'

Comment: @WahidBitar I'm guessing you have `MyGuid.Equals(null)` or `MyGuid.Equals(@0)` and you're passing a parameter of `null` fo `@0`. In either case, make sure the you're using in is `(Guid?)null` or `default(Guid?)` instead of just `null`.

Comment: Thank you for your fast support. I figured it out the easiest way to do it is to use `MyGuid.Value.Equals(anotherValue)`